# How to understand the macro definition

Tags: c++, macros

I'm not a C++ programmer and faced in source code the following macro definition:

```
// HACK: gcc warns about applying offsetof() to non-POD object or calculating
//       offset directly when base address is NULL. Use 16 to get around the
//       warning. gcc-3.4 has an option -Wno-invalid-offsetof to suppress
//       this warning.
#define offset_of(klass,field) (size_t)((intx)&(((klass*)16)->field) - 16)
```

The facts I was confused is these:

1. `((klass*)16)->field)` casting 16 to `klass*` and then inderecting to field `field`?
2. `(intx)&(...)` Bitwise or with `intx` or casting to reference to some type `intx`?

Where `intx` is defined as follows:

```
typedef intptr_t  intx
```

Comment: Depends on what is `intx`.

Comment: @user202729 fixed

Comment: Have you tried looking up all the possible meanings of the symbols there in the docs? That may explains the downvote.

Comment: Very similar to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof why write yourown?

Comment: @RichardCritten The OP didn't write the macro, but they "faced in source code" somewhere.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not my own. This is from open source project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` in this case is an address-of operator, taking the address of `field` within the `klass` type.

The rest of it is just a matter of parenthesis to make sure that you get the RIGHT bits evaluated in the right place, and several casts to ensure that pointer to field is an integer type that can be cast to `size_t`.

Comment: But how can we cast `16` to `klass*`. We don't know the `sizeof(klass)`... And after that we get the field `field`. Why don't we get `SEGFAULT` here?

Comment: Becuse you're immediately taking the address of the value dereferenced pointer, meaning the compiler won't generate any access to the actual field from 16, it will just add the offset of field to the original pointer. Same as if you do `&myvar->field` doesn't actually ACCESS the memory pointed to by `myvar`, it just calculates the address of `field` within the structure. And this won't work if the content of `klass` isn't fully known by the compiler, so yes, the compiler can know sizeof(klass) [but doesn't need to here]

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of such kind of macro is to get memory offset of a specific field in a struct. It's not unusual.

To explain the detail, `(klass*)16` will convert `16` to a pointer, then `(intx)&(((klass*)16)->field)` will look at the address of field `field` and interpret this address as an integer. Combining with the following minus 16, the offset of this field is obtained.

For example:

```
#define offset_of(klass,field) (size_t)((size_t)&(((klass*)16)->field) - 16)

struct foo {
    int   a;
    char  b;
    short c;
};

int main() {
    size_t offset_of_b = offset_of(foo, b);
}
```

Here the `offset_of_b` is just the memory offset of field `b` in the struct `foo`.

Comment: ... This doesn't answer the question. The question is what does the symbols mean.

Comment: Detailed explanation added.

Comment: is 16 just an arbitrary value? or does it mean anything

Comment: The value 16 avoids the compiler thinking that you're taking the address of NULL and optimizing away the "undefined behaviour".

Comment: And probably some alignment things (so you don't use `1`)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I guess you meant dereferencing NULL.

Comment: So i can use any value as long as it is not NULL?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think 0 is ok, I read some implementation of `offsetof` before, which use `#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t) ( (char *)&((st *)(0))->m - (char *)0 ))`.

Comment: Almost any value would work, aside from zero, which gcc warns about, because it thinks you're dereferencing it, and MAY optimize away any code after because "null-pointer accesses won't happen". And avoid overflowing 32-bit signed integers for good results, but that's rarely a porblem these days with 32-bit or more.

Comment: @liliscent: Yes, as long as you don't need it to work in gcc when you take the offset of a class-member [of a non-POD class], it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This macro replaces code whose behavior is undefined with different code whose behavior is also undefined, in an attempt to avoid a warning that the behavior of the first version is undefined.

Trying to analyze why it "works" is a parlor game. It is not engineering. That's why it's labeled "HACK".

Comment: The thing is it looked a bit tricky and I only need to understand what's going on.

Comment: @St.Antario -- again: the behavior is undefined. That means that you **must** investigate how the particular compiler you're using handles that code. Any answer that you get that doesn't say "this only works when you know that the compiler you're using does XXX" is simply wrong.